# Firebase Dynamic Link Empty Analytics

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm generating a dynamic link using The Firebase API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest) and I have followed the first example by making a POST request with a LongDynamicLink field in the body. I got the Long Dynamic Link from the Firebase console, under "Link Info" beside the specific dynamic link I'm trying to track.

This is generating a unique link that I am recording in my database and sending via sms to my phone. Upon clicking the link there is no data recorded in my firebase console.

I have also queried the generated link that was sent to my phone via the Firebase api and it returns and empty json object.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Only short links trigger the analytics - can you test whether it works with a shortlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto-> firebase console-> analysis-> event->dynamic_link_first_open/dynamic_link_app_open